# Wonky multibyte character display in vim when editing over ssh

Tags: vim, character-encoding, ssh

If I just open a terminal and edit a file in vim, multibyte characters display fine:
[image: source file with greek characters]

However, if I ssh into my machine (even just using `ssh localhost`), multibyte characters start looking a bit wonky.  They take up more room on the line (note the extra whitespace at the end of the line with `p1 = "αβγβγγ")`

[image: phantom spaces]

And editing the line tends to display `?` characters as placeholders:

[image: after an xp normal mode command on the alpha]

I think this is some sort of environment, since `:set encoding` reports `utf-8` when not using ssh and `latin1` when using ssh.  I suppose I could hardcode it to `utf-8` in my .vimrc file, but I'd rather figure out what's causing the issue, and fix it more properly.

Answer (score 12):

```
set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8
```

in your `~/.vimrc` should take care of your issue.

Make sure that Terminal.app is itself correctly setup for UTF-8 and that the locale of your machine is also set to some form of UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

`set ambiwidth=double`

in your .vimrc might solve this issue.

Did you tick the check-box labeled `Unicode East Asian Ambiguous characters are wide`?
[image]